# Wrap in Java Generated .sql statements in 50 blocks

Tags: java

I have an application which reads a file and generates sql insert statements. Now I want to merge 50 statements to one block:

My solution doesn't work and is incomplete, because there can be the case that there are only 37 statemets, but then in my case there is the `FROM DUAL; COMMIT;` missing.

I am a little bit stranded. I want to know a proper way, to merge a number of 50 statements and when there are less left, because they are the last statements they should also be merged.

Maybe somebody got some ideas?

**SCHEMA**/**OUTPUT**

```
INSERT
      INTO
      INTO
      INTO.... (total 50 lines)
FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
```

**CODE** (extract)

```
final String template = "INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);";
List<String> statements = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {

........

int counter = 0;
if(counter == 0) {statements.add("INSERT"); }
if(counter == 50) {statements.add("FROM DUAL;\nCOMMIT;"); counter = 0;}
counter++;
statements.add(String.format(template, tableN, cols.toString(), vals.toString())); }
```

Comment: Why don't you move `statements.add("FROM DUAL;\nCOMMIT;");` out of the loop, and insert it right after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the first and the last statements out of the loop:

```
statements.add("INSERT");
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    // ...
    statements.add(String.format(template, tableN, cols.toString(), vals.toString()));
}
statements.add("FROM DUAL;\nCOMMIT;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below

```
 for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++) {

........

int counter = 0;
if(counter == 0) {statements.add("INSERT"); }
if(counter == lines.size) {statements.add("FROM DUAL;\nCOMMIT;"); counter = 0;}
counter++;
statements.add(String.format(template, tableN, cols.toString(), vals.toString())); }
```

or you can also add commit out of the loop to your statement.